# Give a bound of $\|(u_{xx}+u_{yy})\|_p$ by $\|\nabla(\nabla u)\|_p$

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality, poissons-equation

Consider twice differentiable $u$ defined on unit disk, that is constantly zero on the boundary.

Then, is there fixed $a>0$ s.t. $a\|\nabla(\nabla u)\|_p\le \|u_{xx}+u_{yy}\|_p$?

Here, you may choose any $p>1$ as you please.

Comment: This is a bit strange as $\nabla^2 = \Delta$. Do you mean $\Delta^2$?

Comment: It should have been $\|\nabla(\nabla u)\|$. I will change it, thank you.

Comment: In the notation you are using, is $\nabla(\nabla u)$ a $2\times 2$ matrix with $u_{x_i x_j}$ as entries? Because if so you can show $\|\nabla(\nabla u)\|_{L^2} = \|\Delta u\|_{L^2}$. I believe the proof is in Evans, but I can look it up for you.

Comment: Yes, $\nabla(\nabla u)$ means 2 by 2 matrix, and we take a matrix norm and take its lp norm.

Comment: /If that equality holds, that would be a perfect answer for this question.

Comment: Let me write out the proof of that for you!

Comment: Okay, the proof is bit more involved than I thought, Evans assumes that the first order derivatives of $u$ vanish on the boundary as well as $u$ itself. Still I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information and I'll expect your further result!